# Highest Sum Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been googling for a while being unable to find my answer.
I'm trying to get a single cell formula that returns with the Highest Sum of a listed item. So for example I have:

```
Value   Name
   4    James
   5    James
   1    Kari
   50   (Blank)
   7    Kari
   3    James
```

Kari's has 8 days total, James has 12 total, and "Blank" is discarded. I'd like the formula to return just "12". I can get this to work using Max(), and Sumifs(), but that requires additional fields and formulas. Is there a clean way to do this in one in a single cell formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as an array formula:

```
=MAX(SUMIFS($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7,"<>"))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]